# Keras Own Training routine vs Keras Fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to compare the results of my own training loop with the one given by Keras Fit. I provide a code snippet below (RUN_TYPE = 1 runs own training loop, else run Keras fit) . As you can see:

1. I seed the rnds so my generated training set is exactly the same (checked).
2. I use the same  function to create the DNN architecture.
3. I use the same hyperparameter values (learning rate, optimised parameters, batch_size, etc)
4. I specifically use `shuffle=False` in the Keras.fit function to disable any batch shuffling.

When I set batch_size to the size of the training sample, I get the same loss between the two versions. As soon as batch_size < training sample size, i.e. an epoch takes multiple steps, my results diverge. Having made the algo deterministic I don't understand where the discrepancy comes from.

Any tips?

```
RUN_TYPE = 2
import numpy as np
import time
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

np.random.seed(1)
tf.random.set_seed(2)


@tf.function
def training_step(x, y, model, opt):
    print(x)
    print(y)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(x, training=True)
        mseLoss = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
        loss = mseLoss(y,predictions)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
    return loss
    

#HyperParameters Initialisation
#learnging_rate, beta_1, beta_2, blablabla.


if RUN_TYPE == 1:
        X_train, y_train = createDataSet(n)
        train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
        train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
        # An optimizer for updating the trainable variables
        optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate, beta_1=beta_1, beta_2=beta_2)
        # Create an instance of the model
        model = createModel(X_train.shape[1:])
        # Train the model
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
            for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
                loss = training_step(x_batch_train, y_batch_train, model, optimizer)
                print("Step " + str(step) + " loss = " + str(loss.numpy()))
else:
        X, Y = createDataSet(n)
        model = createModel(X.shape[1:])
        optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate, beta_1=beta_1, beta_2=beta_2)
        model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)
        history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, shuffle=False) #
```